# VB.NET remove specific chars between two characters in a string

Tags: string, vb.net

In vb.net how do i remove a character from string which occurs between two known characters in a series.For example how do you remove commas from the number occurring between the hashtag

Balance,#163,464.24#,Cashbook Closing Balance:,#86,689.45#,Money,End

Comment: While enumerating characters use a flag for `hashtag` and remove commas when flag is `true`. Set the flag to `false` on next occurrence of `#`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this simple and efficient approach using a loop and a `StringBuilder`:

```
Dim text = "Balance,#163,464.24#,Cashbook Closing Balance:,#86,689.45#,Money,End"
Dim textBuilder As New StringBuilder()
Dim inHashTag As Boolean = False

For Each c As Char In text
    If c = "#"c Then inHashTag = Not inHashTag ' reverse Boolean
    If Not inHashTag OrElse c <> ","c Then
        textBuilder.Append(c) ' append if we aren't in hashtags or the char is not a comma
    End If
Next
text = textBuilder.ToString()
```

Comment: This is definitely a much safer suggestion than mine.

Comment: @tim schmelter thank that worked perfectly, thank you too @A Friend

Answer (score -1):

Because I'm bad at regex:

```
Dim str = "Balance,#163,464.24#,Cashbook Closing Balance:,#86,689.45#,Money,End"
Dim split = str.Split("#"c)
If UBound(split) > 1 Then
    For i = 1 To UBound(split) Step 2
        split(i) = split(i).Replace(",", "")
    Next
End If
str = String.Join("#", split)
```